# Is there any document that contains all web vulnerabilities of OWASP?

Tags: vulnerability

[OWASP top 10](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) lists the top 10 web security risks.

But I didn't find the other vulnerabilities out of the top 10 in OWASP site.
Is there any document that contains all web vulnerabilities?

Comment: I googled "owasp vulnerabilities". Top hit was the top 10. The second hit was the page that lists all the vulnerabilities. Searching using the OWASP site's search bar, also returns the page you are looking for as the top hit.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions that ask for resources/sources are off-topic (and searchable, anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top 10 are there due to their criticality, meaning that they are the ones that are most responsible for data leaks, web degradation and so on ... The OWASP has a lot of vulnerabilities you should check this link:

[Web Application Vulnerabilities.](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/)

Comment: Does your given link list all kinds of Web vulnerabilities?

Comment: @244boy did you even open the link?